# Не могу выбрать метод скрипта который прицепил к UI кнопке

Tags: c#, unity3d-ui

[image: Скрин Unity]

```
public void LoadNextScene() {

    int currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;

    SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneIndex + 1);

}
```

Comment: Проверь в свойствах кнопки  к какому методу привязано событие, которое тебе нужно

Comment: К событию On click никаких функций не подключено (потому что в списке их нет)